Karate tests are not getting executed. Stopped at " com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js"
I am using karate for past 3-4 years and recently in a new laptop, I am unable to run Karate tests. I have done the required setup, installed JDK 23 and Maven.
When I tried to run mvn clean test, it is always getting stopped at this line and not moving forward.
[main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js

I am using Windows 11
Karate Version: 1.4.0
My Java version: java version "23.0.1" 2024-10-15
Maven version: Apache Maven 3.9.9
I don't know if I missed anything. Please suggest any solution.
I have tried with latest JDK version. Also tried with Latest Karate Version.
Same problem faced in VSCode terminal and also windows CMD prompt execution.

This is a known problem with old versions of Karate and the latest JDKs. Upgrade to Karate 1.5.0 or downgrade your JDK to 21.

Thank you @PeterThomas I just downgraded the java version to 21 and it's working fine.
